# Display image from url in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added UIImageView in my xib, connected its IB named 'codeImage' to the file owner, synthesized in .m and autolayout is unchecked.

```
    NSURL *urlForImage = [NSURL URLWithString:@" url "];
    NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForImage];

    UIImage *imageData = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
    self.qrCodeImage.image = imageData;
```

Couldn't display image. Is there something I missed?

Comment: are you getting data in dataImage ?

Comment: Did you verify that `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForImage]` is actually returning any data? Please consider using `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` to get information about any errors that may be happening

Comment: enter URL in browser and check image are there or not.

Comment: @LuisCien there is no error.. i tried dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and I get error = (null) but still no image.

Comment: @KiritModi I have added the url in my code. Please copy paste and check it in your browser as well. I get the image in browser.

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly. Image gets downloaded and displayed. Please check your network and image view `IBOutlet` if it is properly connected.

Comment: Me too tried it and it works perfectly. It may some other issue with your IB connection or any other code over riding the action of above code.

Comment: hey the issue is resolved. Please check my answer to my this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an unused UIImage *image = nil and I set [qrCodeImage setImage:image]; rite at the end of the viewDidLoad.. Code in the question itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://bwwapp.com/mvbritt/toolimg/mobilethumbs
/%@",[[getOneByOne objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"iimg"]];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
```